# TinyMCE bombing out in Kentico after upgrade to 13

Tags: tinymce, kentico, kentico-12, kentico-mvc

I have a Kentico site that I inherited that I am getting towards the end of updating to Kentico 13.0.106. It has one problem that is pretty major for me at the moment. At the moment, TinyMCE is breaking, and the Wysiwyg editor is not showing. None of the pages in Content > Pages is therefore editable.

I'm not sure if this is a problem, but the application was including a third-party component that was created by DevTrev called HBS.TinyMCE_Wysiwyg.Kentico.MVC. Because that is locked to Kentico 12, I had to find the source code (luckily Trev published it to github [here](https://github.com/KenticoDevTrev/TinyMCE_Wysiwyg))

I was able to go in and upgrade the referenced Kentico packages, rebuild the assemblies with Kentico 13.0.106, upgrade my live site to the same version, and reference the new assemblies.

The problem is, TinyMCE isn't working now and I'm not sure why.

When I open a dialog containing the TinyMCE control, it gives me an error:
[image: PageNotFound error]

When I click in the TinyMCE control, I get the following error:
[image: Node is undefined error]

The CMS Admin and live site are both dot net framework 4.8.1 (dot net 6 will come later)

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you have installed a third party module or plugin. You'll need to make sure that plug in or module is able to be upgraded to 13 as well. Once you can determine that, then you should be able to go back to that module or plug in find that source code and apply that update to your current version.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to find a way to fix the component that is there.

Comment: Or, I would recommend submitting an issue on the plugins's Github - DevTrev - So Trevor can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by reading the Kentico documentation on how to add in custom components, then copying the code in from the package that was relevant to my project. By removing the old packages, it broke the app, and then it was a matter of finding out what code that belonged to in the package and copying it all in until there were no more breaks. All worke in the end.